# C# Unity program ignores Listener when calling certain method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, event-handling, listener

I am doing `onClick.Addlistener()` on a unity button in my settings ui setup code. I need to add a listener to the back button, to return to the main menu. Now when i put my call to go to the main menu in there it looks like this: `myButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate() { gm.uiManager.ToMainMenu(); });` this however doesn't work. all the elements (gm, uiManager and ToMainMenu) do exist. However they don't get called for some reason...
If i put `Debug.Log("Test")` into that same delegate it gets called...
So uhhhh why doesn't my other method get called? I have tried putting it into a seperate method too and debugging with a breakpoint... it just doesn't pass that code at all... it doesn't error out... I am lost...

Here is the entire source code: https://github.com/SupraEntertainment/RhythmicVR/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/RhythmicVR/SettingsManager.cs (line 19 is where i add the listener)

And I am sincerely sorry for not having any commenting on that code.. I will go over all my code and add method documentation and comments eventually...

Comment: Not related just btw: Why are you inheriting from `Object` ?

Comment: And just to be clear if you write `delegate { Debug.Log("Before"); gm.uiManager.ToMainMenu(); Debug.Log("After"); }` You see both logs but your method isn't called? Can you add a `Debug.Log("Yeay!");` at the top of that `ToMainMenu()` method?

Comment: no, as soon as i add my method call nothing in that delegate happens. no log and no main menu

Comment: oh and that Object was just for some unity function i was using. I am inheriting from UnityEngine.Object. not System.Object or whatever the default is

Comment: Have you tried removing the parentheses from delegate?  i.e `myButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate { gm.uiManager.ToMainMenu(); });`

Comment: @HumanWrites `delegate(){ someMethod(); }`, `delegate{ someMethod(); }`, `() => someMethod();` and `someMethod` should all do the same here ...

Comment: I did a workaround for now to go to the main menu, but no matter how i formulate that delegate or if i use it at all.. it just won't call that specific method for some reason..
My workaround looks good either way and might just stay.. its wierd though nontheless